# How to show JSON array into Listview of Fragment?

Tags: android-fragments

I am trying to implement Listview in Fragment, All items from URL is fetched but unable to do show in Listview. I am using Navigation Drawer and this fragment is one of the item of Drawer. my code is here:     Thanks in advance

```
public class ViewEmployeeFragment extends Fragment {
    String  Fname,Email,Userlogname,Phone,Company,Lname;
            ListView empListView;
            Context context;
            ArrayList<HashMap<String , String>> ListFirstname = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
CustomBaseAdapter mAdapter;
    public ViewEmployeeFragment(){

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vuemploye_fragment, container, false);
        empListView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork().penaltyLog().build());
try{
            JSONObject jobject = getJSON();
            JSONArray jArry = jobject.getJSONArray("data");
            for(int j=0; j<jArry.length(); j++){

                JSONObject jObj = jArry.getJSONObject(j);

                Fname = jObj.getString(NAME);
                Company = jObj.getString(COMPANY);
                Email = jObj.getString(EMAIL);
                Lname = jObj.getString(LNAME);
                Userlogname = jObj.getString(USERLOGNAME);
                Phone = jObj.getString(PHONE);

                Log.i("Json Value", "First Name: "+Fname);
                Log.i("Json Value", "Company Name: "+Company);
                Log.i("Json Value", "Email: "+Email);
                Log.i("Json Value", "Last name: "+Lname);
                Log.i("Json Value", "User ID: "+Userlogname);
                Log.i("Json Value", "Phone: "+Phone);
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(NAME, Fname);
                ListFirstname.add(map);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
empListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        return rootView;
}
public JSONObject getJSON(){
          JSONObject jArray = null ;
          StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
          Log.d("Inside creater", "creating JSON string");

          HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

          HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://fwdfuture.com/locationapp/ds-emp-list.php?admid=7");


          try{
              HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
               StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
               Log.d("Httpresponse", ""+httpResponse);
               int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
               Log.d("Status Code ", " is " +statusCode);
               if(statusCode == 200){
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
                  InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));
                String line;
                while((line = br.readLine())!= null){

                 sBuilder.append(line);
                 Log.d("Getting Json", "Json Data Download "+'\n'+sBuilder);
                }
               }
               else{
                Log.d("Error", "Failed to Download");
                }

              }catch(Exception e){
               Log.d("Exception", ""+e);
              }
          try{
               jArray = new JSONObject(sBuilder.toString());
               Log.d("JSON array", ""+jArray);
              }catch(Exception e ){
               e.printStackTrace();
              }
              return jArray;
             }

public class CustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        private Context activity;
        LayoutInflater inflatr;
//      private ArrayList<String> Lfname = null;
        public CustomBaseAdapter(Context activity){
            this.activity = activity;
//          inflatr = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            inflatr = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return ListFirstname.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return ListFirstname.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(convertView == null){
                    convertView = inflatr.inflate(R.layout.emplist_item, parent, false);
            }
            HashMap<String, String> map = ListFirstname.get(position);
            TextView EmpName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1_empName);
            String S_emp = map.get(NAME);
            EmpName.setText(S_emp);
            return convertView;
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to make adapter using baseadapter class, and set this adapter in listview.[click here to view example](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/listview-with-custom-adapter.html)